# Remote monitor PC status

Tags: monitoring

Is there a way I can monitor whether multiple ubuntu systems are powered up and online, and also set automatic shutdown times?

I'm very new to Linux and looked into nagios, but from what I can tell it comes with many features that I would not need and is also a paid service which I can't invest in for the time being.

Comment: You can monitor multiple ubuntu systems using system monitor.Second method is using saidar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to do this, 
for checking if the computers are on, you could use ping to see if the machine responds:

```
ping -c1 ipadress
```

or if you want it more convenient, make a script and add all of of them.

Since you said you are new to linux, i am assuming you don't know how to make a bash script.
Just make a new text file (say you call it check-if-up.sh), with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# machine 1
ping -c1 ipadress &> /dev/null && echo "machine 1 is up" || echo "machine 1 is down"

# machine 2
ping -c1 ipadress &> /dev/null && echo "machine 2 is up" || echo "machine 2 is down"
# ..
```

The command there will ping the ip, and echo one of the 2 answers depending if up or down. You need to give it permissions to run with

```
chmod +x check-if-up.sh
```

then you can run it with

```
./check-if-up.sh
```

It should output something like

```
machine 1 is up
machine 2 is down
...
```

For shutting down the system the shutdown command itself supports a time already.

To shutdown at a specific time (using 24h time)

```
sudo shutdown -h 8:15
```

or after a certain amnount of time (say, in 10 minutes)

```
sudo shutdown -h +10
```

You could also add this command to the crontab to be repeated every day, in case it never changes. I believe there are also graphical shutdown timer apps in the software center, so if you prefer that try a search there.